# What can I use to prevent fingerprints on a touch screen monitor whilst naturally emulating touch screen use?

Tags: display, touchscreen, fingerprint

I'm a web developer who is currently waiting for a touch-screen monitor to be delivered as a replacement for my current one. I don't intend on using the touch functionality of the screen all that much; only when I'm testing out touch-screen usability on certain sites. The problem is that I'm not really wanting a load of fingerprints and smudges all over the screen and I don't necessarily want to have to clean the monitor every time I use its touch functionality.

Are there any really thin gloves (would latex gloves work?) or covers that I can put over the screen (or my fingers?) that would emulate the natural feel of using a touch-screen monitor without leaving undesirable marks?

Sorry if this isn't the sort of question which should be asked here!

Comment: this is the right place to ask :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make touch screen capable gloves out of *any* gloves.  All you need is a conductive [thread](http://www.kobakant.at/DIY/?p=379) - definitely non-abrasive.

Check out this Google [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20make%20touchscreen%20gloves&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS513US513&oq=how%20to%20mak&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j69i60j69i65l3.1312j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and see the many methods out there.

In the end, you dont even need gloves, any conductive item that you can stick to the end of your finger will work.